# Addons don't install

Tags: add-on

I've installed addons before, but recently when I upload the addon into blender, and I search for the addon, nothing shows. I'm not unzipping the file, so I'm not sure what's wrong? In the bottom right, when it shows the file you install, it just shows this. Is that supposed to be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the add-ons look for your category to the left, such as rigging, select it, and look for your add-on. If its still not there, then maybe you could try moving the file around on your laptop or desktop.